# Freenas ( or some other) for Asus NAS M25

Tags: file-management

I just got my self a Asus M25 nas system and I'm wondering is it possible to install some other system to it? I have searched some examples and so far with no luck. Any good ideas?

Comment: What are you looking for in such a system? What features do you need?

Comment: That it is maintained.. I think Asus is not updating their system and I don't feel safe to plug this old machine in and add my personal pictures to there